# Apart from Alfvenic turbulence, what is the most important unsolved problems in plasma physics?

Tags: plasma-physics

**Apart from [Alfvénic turbulence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfvenic_Turbulence)**, 
what is the most important unsolved problems in plasma physics?
Is there a review article describing some important unsolved problems in plasma physics, I repeat, apart from turbulence, which is an unsolved matter in all areas of physics.

Comment: [Major Unsolved Problems in Space Plasma Physics](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1012264131485) [List of unsolved problems in physics(Wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_physics) [Plasma turbulence "undoubtedly belongs to the most important unsolved problems of classical physics."](http://www.princeton.edu/plasmacenter/research/plasma-turbulence/)

Comment: This question has been flagged for reopening. It's status is currently being debated in [meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4561). I am voting to keep closed (it was for good reason as being an unproductive question) unless and until a consensus is reached there saying otherwise. Please do not try to sneak in a policy circumvention, even if one is in the process of appealing that policy.